# How to recursively grab class/tree/json information

Tags: c#, html, json, recursion

Good afternoon All,

I have an issue that I'm struggling to deal with

I am working with a third party Questions/Answers API,  I ask it for a bunch of questions, and it supplies them with possible answers, which can lead to more questions

For now I just want to render them out in HTML but my issue is, that I am de-serializing the JSON from their web service into C# classes,  The original JSON looks like

```
{
   "questionDetails":[
      {
         "templateId":"T1000515",
         "trees":[
            {
               "questions":[
                  {
                     "questionPhrase":"can this customer reported issue can be caused by accidental damage",
                     "answerType":"INT",
                     "questionId":"I100461"
                  },
                  {
                     "questionPhrase":"What damage is present on the display glass?",
                     "questionId":"Q100973",
                     "answers":[
                        {
                           "answerPhrase":"Single hairline crack with no point of impact",
                           "answerId":"A105795"
                        },
                        {
                           "answerPhrase":"Single hairline crack with a point of impact",
                           "answerId":"A105796"
                        },
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "questionPhrase":"Was the customer using any third party accessories on the display?",
                     "questionId":"Q217845",
                     "answers":[
                        {
                           "answerPhrase":"Yes",
                           "questions":[
                              {
                                 "questionPhrase":"Will the customer cover the cost of repair",
                                 "questionId":"I217846",
                                 "answers":[
                                 {
                                    "answerPhrase":"Yes",
                                    "answerId":"A20062"
                                 },
                                 {
                                     "answerPhrase":"No",
                                    "answerId":"A20063"
                                 }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ],
                           "answerId":"A20062"
                        },
                        {
                           "answerPhrase":"No",
                           "answerId":"A20063"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "treeId":"TREE101678"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The Standard question->answer is fine but there are some examples where its question->answer->question->answer->question->answer and I am guessing it can be recursive up to 10-15 questions for some devices.

I'm not really sure how to attack the problem,  I first though of maybe trying to create a generic tree and then rendering that tree, but Im not sure if I need to use reflection to check the Class,  or really  how to say if answer causes more questions, keep adding, without writing a ton of if statements

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It seems like we started to solve this the same day. I've been thinking about rendering the tree as a flat UL list with checkboxes and possible text or number boxes at the branches, with some hidden type inputs at the same level describing the path, then parsing it back to the questionDetail. Surely it could be more user friendly with some AJAX/jQuery clickers but it's out of my reach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one method that asks the question and then use the recursive way of asking other questions if they exist. Wrote an example of how you can recursively call the method (AskQuestion) but only a simple way of showing how a recursive method can be used.

```
// Starting point with a list of questions.
private static void AskQuestion(List<Questions> questions)
{
    foreach (Questions question in questions)
        Console.WriteLine(question.QuestionId + ": " + question.QuestionPhrase);
    
    Console.Write("Select Question: ");
    string ID = Console.ReadLine();

    Questions selectedQuestion = questions.Where(x => x.QuestionId.Equals(ID)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (selectedQuestion.Answers != null)
    {
        foreach (Answers answers in selectedQuestion.Answers)
            Console.WriteLine(answers.AnswerId + ": " + answers.AnswerPhrase);

        Console.Write("Select Answer: ");
        ID = Console.ReadLine();
        Answers answer = selectedQuestion.Answers.Where(x => x.AnswerId.Equals(ID)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (answer.Questions != null && answer.Questions.Count > 0)
            AskQuestion(answer.Questions); // <-- This is where you would recursively call the AskQuestion method for further questions.
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Hope you got the answer you were looking for");
    }
}

public class Questionaire
{
    [JsonProperty("questionDetails")]
    public List<QuestionDetails> QuestionDetails { get; set; }
}
public class QuestionDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("templateId")]
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("trees")]
    public List<Trees> Trees { get; set; }
}

public class Trees
{
    [JsonProperty("questions")]
    public List<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("treeId")]
    public string TreeId { get; set; }
}

public class Questions
{
    [JsonProperty("questionPhrase")]
    public string QuestionPhrase { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("answerType")]
    public string AnswerType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("questionId")]
    public string QuestionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("answers")]
    public List<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answers
{
    [JsonProperty("answerPhrase")]
    public string AnswerPhrase { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("answerId")]
    public string AnswerId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("questions")]
    public List<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

and in the main, you can simply do,

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Questionaire>(json);
AskQuestion(obj.QuestionDetails.First().Trees.First().Questions);
```

Comment: This should work perfectly for what I was attempting,  Thank you!

Comment: Great! Hey @DatenThielt, have you found out how to return the value when answerType is INT? Is it just by giving answerId? or via answerPhrase? And what the other answerTypes are? I would only guess "radio " and "checkbox"...

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one fighting this! (Damn apple)  but yep,  They really did not make this simple eh?  It gets even more fun when you realize some questions marked mandatory are actually not, and some are when marked otherwise!

Comment: Yep - the swagger is OK but some parts just leave so much to figuring out for yourself. BTW I've just checked the old SOAP doc and the answerTypes are there much better described!

Comment: A relief is that INT type is just inline text and needs no reply despite being not optional. PS: a reminder that the new API is under NDA she we shall not mention the mothership...